# Pivot rows to columns by date pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, pivot, pivot-table

I have a Pandas DataFrame called df that looks like this:

```
Date           String

2016-08-01      a
2016-08-01      b
2016-08-01      c
2016-06-30      d
2016-06-30      e
2016-06-30      f
```

And I am trying to obtain:

```
Date           Column1      Column2        Column3

2016-08-01       a             b              c
2016-06-30       d             e              f
```

I tried using:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Date')
```

or:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Date'], values="News")
```

but I keep receiving:

> pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `cumcount` to get repeating counts for date, then use `pivot`:

```
(df.assign(Count=df.groupby('Date').cumcount()+1)
   .pivot('Date', 'Count', 'String')
   .add_prefix('Column'))

Count      Column1 Column2 Column3
Date                              
2016-06-30       d       e       f
2016-08-01       a       b       c
```

---

Or, `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
(df.set_index(['Date', df.groupby('Date').cumcount()+1])['String']
   .unstack()
   .add_prefix('Column'))

           Column1 Column2 Column3
Date                              
2016-06-30       d       e       f
2016-08-01       a       b       c
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is with `groupy`, `apply(list)` and after that converting the list values to seperate columns with `Series.values.tolist()`

```
# Groupby and get the values in a list per unique value of the Date column
df = df.groupby('Date').String.apply(list).reset_index()

    Date        String
0   2016-06-30  [d, e, f]
1   2016-08-01  [a, b, c]

# Convert the values from the list to seperate columns and after that drop the String column
df[['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3']] = pd.DataFrame(df.String.values.tolist(), index=df.index)
df.drop('String', axis=1, inplace=True)


    Date        Column1 Column2 Column3
0   2016-06-30  d       e       f
1   2016-08-01  a       b       c
```